# How to expand all menu items when hovering top level, and removing them again when going out of scope?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a three-leveled menu. When entering the site, all levels of the menu should be hidden except level-1. When hovering level-1, all sub menu's should be displayed (both level-2 and level-3)

My menu looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Whn6/1/

```
<ul class="nav">
<li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60 actives hover"><a href="#/?page_id=37">CHAPTERS</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-77 arrow hover"><a href="#/?product_cat=one">ONE</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-76 hover"><a href="#/?product=test">ROMAN NET</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-80 hover"><a href="#/?product=white-shadow">WHITE SHADOW</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-81 hover"><a href="#/?product=armor">ARMOR</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-83 arrow hover"><a href="#/?product_cat=two">TWO</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-85 hover"><a href="#/?product=coming-soon">coming soon</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

​The CSS i have come up with is currently this:

```
ul.nav li > ul > li { display: none }
```

Which makes the site only display the top level.

How do i expand all the other levels on hover, and remove them again when unhovering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simplest form,

```
    ul.nav li > ul > li { display: none; }
​    ul.nav li:hover li { display: block; }
    ul.nav > li { background-color: #eee; }
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqGAp/)

One of your `ul` has `style="display: none;"` set inline on it...get rid of that if you want to show it. [View that edit on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqGAp/1/).